# Warning message in older perl version

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, warnings

I have the following code in my script:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each @values) {
    if ( $key < $arraySize-1) {
        if ( $values[$key+1] eq "user") {
            $endcon=1;
        }
    }
    if ( ( $startcon == 1 ) && ( $endcon != 1 ) ) {
        $UptimeString .= $value;
    }
    if ( $value eq "up") {
        $startcon=1;
    }
    if ( $value eq "average:") {
        $LoadMinOne=$values[$key+1];
    }
}
```

While compiling it, in perl 5.14, I have no warnings, but in perl 5.10.1, I have this warning: `Type of arg 1 to each must be hash (not private array) at ./uptimep.pl line 21, near "@values) "`

Line 21 is `while (my ($key, $value) = each @values) {`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in error message, `each` must have a hash for parameter, but you give it an array.

You could replace this line:

```
 while (my ($key, $value) = each @values) {
```

by:

```
for my $key(0 .. $#values) {
    my $value = $values[$key];
```

According to the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) `each` accepts array as parameter from perl 5.12.0

Comment: Why is it not an error in perl 5.14? Perldoc does provide each for array and hashes.

Comment: @Droidzone: since the each function has become polymorphic as of 5.12.0; see [the perl docs 5.12.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/functions/each.html) vs. [5.10.1](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/functions/each.html).

Comment: `for my $key ( 0..$#values )` is right sintax. `0..@values` will try to access to not defined last+1 element of array

Answer (score -1):

as it says, `each` expects a hash as an argument, not an array.

you can populate a hash first ( `my %hash = @values;` ) and use it as an argument ( `while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash)` ).